# Laravel Websockets reverse proxy port Nginx config to Apache virtual host

Tags: php, laravel, apache, proxy

I'm trying to deploy my [Laravel Websockets](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#usage-with-a-reverse-proxy-like-nginx) application as part of my Laravel 8 API project. Everything works locally, but after deploying I'm unable to connect to port `6001` on my website's domain, which is a sub-domain.

I'm using a Cent OS 8 server with Apache and already have port 80 open to my website on https://api.example.com/, and in order for my site on https://site.example.com/ I've gone ahead and created a sub-domain called https://api-socket.example.com/ and need to proxy this through to port `6001`.

The [config](https://beyondco.de/docs/laravel-websockets/basic-usage/ssl#usage-with-a-reverse-proxy-like-nginx) for a Nginx server I've tried to replace as a virtual host but when I restart httpd I get a 521 error with Cloudflare, my config is:

**/etc/httpd/sites-available/api-socket.example.com.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName api-socket.example.com

    <Proxy *>
        Require all granted
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    SSLEngine on
    SSLProxyEngine on
    SSLProxyVerify none
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule .* wss://127.0.0.1:6001%{REQUEST_URI} [P]
    ProxyPass / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
    ProxyPassReverse / ws://127.0.0.1:6001
</VirtualHost>
```

I have certbot installed, and after generating a SSL I get a Let's Encrypt variant of the above file with `*:443` but then my web server stops running?

What am I missing here to create a proxy so that when I go to https://api-socket.example.com/ it simply proxies through to the web socket server running on the localhost of the server on that port?

Comment: That's the intention of the above config, thus it lives on `api-socket.example.com` so that it's just for sockets, that's why it's got `6001` in the URL, do you have some example?

Comment: What is the Apache version on your server?

Comment: @Haridarshan Apache version: `Apache/2.4.37 (centos)`, with certbot installed and using Cloudflare for SSL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please give it a try without ssl to ensure the configuration works or not.
Make sure following modules are enabled

```
a2enmod proxy
a2enmod proxy_http
a2enmod proxy_wstunnel
```

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName api-socket.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           ws://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6001/
</VirtualHost>
```

If this configuration works, try this same configuration for port `443` with slight modifications

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    ServerName api-socket.example.com

    RewriteEngine On
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    ProxyRequests Off
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule ^/ws/(.*)       wss://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket [NC]
    RewriteRule /(.*)           http://127.0.0.1:6001/$1 [P,L]

    ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:6001/
</VirtualHost>
```

**Update:**
If above doesn't work, just found a link to make it work with Apache, Certbot and Cloudflare https://github.com/cdr/code-server/discussions/2104#discussioncomment-360665

Comment: Okay, so I've got all of that set up, not sure how to check `a2enmod` installation since running those doesn't return any results on my Cent OS 8 server, just says command not found. Furthermore, when I visit my page at https://api-socket.example.com/ I get a 404 not found, and the `/laravel-websockets` page when connecting to `6001` tries to connect to `wss://api.example.com:6001/app/local` so I thought it would've worked?

Comment: It looks like `a2enmod` is for Ubunto, not Centos?

Comment: yes.. you can check installed module via this command `httpd -M | grep -i proxy`

Comment: set `DocumentRoot` to path of the code-base in vhost conf